# Electron app freezes in production build when there are no errors and no memory leaks, what have I done wrong?

Tags: reactjs, electron, create-react-app, electron-builder

I am having some issues with electron app which is built using create-react-app. The app runs fine for just over an a hour but then it will freeze and the PC also freezes. I thought it may have been a memory leak so I added cleanup functions to my useEffects to clear my Timeout/Interval functions. Not sure what the issue might be?

I don't know what to exactly share but I will leave the github repo below. The app uses a local api using express for data. You will need to run the api and the electron app for the app to work. Please run the develop branch for both as that's the latest one I currently working on.

API Github repo: https://github.com/HabibAli786/digital-prayer-api
React-App-Repo: https://github.com/HabibAli786/my-digital-prayer-display

Please run

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, crashReporter } = require('electron' )
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()

app.disableHardwareAcceleration()

crashReporter.start({ uploadToServer: false })

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        show: false,
        frame: false,
        icon: __dirname + '/icon.png',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            devTools: false
        }
    })
    win.maximize()
    // win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')

    win.loadURL(
        isDev
            ? 'http://localhost:3000'
            : `file://${__dirname}/../build/index.html`
    )
}

// app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('ready', () => {
    // Create the new window
    createWindow();
});

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('active', function() {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your window object `win` may be being garbage collected.

To ensure this doesn't happen:

1. Move the declaration of `win` to the global scope.
2. Return `win` at the end of your `createWindow()` function.
3. Allocate the returned window object to the global `win` object when calling `createWindow()`.

---

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, crashReporter } = require('electron' );
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');

require('@electron/remote/main').initialize();

app.disableHardwareAcceleration();

crashReporter.start({ uploadToServer: false });

// Prevent garbage colelction
let win;

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        show: false,
        frame: false,
        icon: __dirname + '/icon.png',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            devTools: false
        }
    });

    win.maximize();
    // win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');

    win.loadURL(
        isDev
            ? 'http://localhost:3000'
            : `file://${__dirname}/../build/index.html`
    );

    return win;
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    // Create the new window
    win = createWindow();
});

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('active', function() {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

Comment: Surprisingly I changed to a slightly more powerful PC and it works fine on it (no freezing). I no longer have the PC that kept freezing so I am unable to test this code. Thanks for the help